# can we check applicationwillresignActive in iphone simulator?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiapplicationdelegate

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"resigning active status...");
}
```

i have tried hardware-lock in iphone simulator but this isn't called. I do want to call it in another UIviewcontroller class not in the appdelegate itself.I also added  in the viewController's header File.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate%5FProtocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple%5Fref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive:), the "applicationWillResignActive" method will get called if the device is locked.

As such pressing Command-L (or "Hardware" >> "Lock"" in the menu) will cause the iPhone simulator to lock and hopefully trigger this method.

Answer (score 2):

I could only get this code to work in the AppDelegate file as well.

You could trying adding your view controller as an observer using the NSNotificationCenter,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(foo) name:@"AppResigned" object:nil];
```

Then in the applicationWillResign post the notification,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AppResigned" object:nil];
```

Hope that helps!